# .NET 7 OutputCache Not Using Named Policies

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to understand OutputCaching but I am running into some problems:

- Caching does work, but it's applying to all controller endpoints even if they don't have the attribute. I think this might be due to AddBasePolicy() but I'm more confused about my next point
- My named policy does not seem to be recognised on the GetElementCached method, the base policy of 5 second expiry always applies. If I remove the base policy caching does not work at all

I have registered the service and subsequently middleware as follows:

```
                .AddOutputCache(options =>
                {
                    options.AddBasePolicy(builder =>
                        builder.Expire(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));

                    options.AddPolicy("DemoCache", builder =>
                        builder.Expire(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)));
                })
```

I have then created two controllers returning test data:

```
        [HttpGet("{index}/get-element-cache")]
        [OutputCache(PolicyName = "DemoCache")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetElementCached(int index)
        {
            return Ok(_myDb[index]);
        }

        [HttpGet("{index}/get-element-no-cache")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetElementNoCache(int index)
        {
            return Ok(_myDb[index]);
        }
```

I've checked worked examples and the documentation and I'm confused why my policy won't apply especially given the base policy works and can be changed making me *believe* I've configured it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> applying to all controller endpoints even if they don't have the
> attribute

Create policies when calling AddOutputCache to specify caching configuration that applies to multiple endpoints. A base policy provides default caching configuration for a collection of endpoints.You can read [Configure multiple endpoints or pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/output?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-multiple-endpoints-or-pages) to know more.

> My named policy does not seem to be recognised on the GetElementCached
> method,

I  create an ASP.NET Core Web API project using the default template, before we add the basic caching, let’s run our app and hit the default Weather Forecast . We notice that each time we refresh, we get a different result. This is due to the default code randomizing the results.

Then make two small changes to Program.cs: add the output caching middleware to the service collection and request pipeline respectively. :

```
builder.Services.AddOutputCache(options =>
 {
     options.AddBasePolicy(builder =>
         builder.Expire(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));

     options.AddPolicy("DemoCache", builder =>
         builder.Expire(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)));
 });
...
app.UseOutputCache();
```

Then  test WeatherForecast to see the result,:

```
        [HttpGet("{index}/get-element-cache")]
        [OutputCache(PolicyName = "DemoCache")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetElementCached()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }

        [HttpGet("{index}/get-element-no-cache")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetElementNoCache()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
```

Result: after we hit the URL again, we can see that the response is being cached for 20 seconds now :

[image]